# The proof of Cantor's Intersection Theorem on nested compact sets

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

The book "Metric Spaces" by Babu Ram says this about the proof of [Cantor's Intersection Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem):

> Create nested intervals $F_{n+1}\subset F_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\text{diameter}(F_n)=0$. Choose points $x_i\in F_i$. $\{x_i\}$ is a cauchy sequence. Hence, by the completeness property of the metric space, it has a limit point in the space. Let it be $a$. Our claim is that $a\in\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} F_i$.
>
> Let us assume to the contrary. Then there is an $F_k$ such that $a\notin F_k$, and hence $a\notin F_j$ for all $j\geq k$. Let $r=d(a,F_k)$. **Then $r>0$**. Hence, $B(a,\frac{r}{2})$ does not contain any of the points $x_e$, $e\geq k$. Therefore, it can't be the limit point of $\{x_i\}$.

**My question**

Why can't $r=0$? For example, if $F_k=(1,2)$, and $a=1$, then $$d(a,F_k)=\inf\{ d(a,y): y\in F_k\}=0$$ If $r=0$, then doesn't this whole proof fall flat? Clearly checking whether $B(a,0)$ contains any of the points of $\{x_i\}$, and hence checking whether it is a convergent point of $\{x_i\}$ makes no sense.

Comment: The intervals should be closed.

Comment: If you allow open intervals, Cantor isn't true. For example, $\bigcap \left(0,\frac1n\right)$ is empty.

Comment: But the link just says "compact sets". Can open sets in complete metric spaces not be compact?

Comment: Compact subsets of the real line are exactly the closed bounded subsets of the real line. Open intervals are not closed subsets of the real line. @AyushKhaitan

Comment: I think the theorem you want to prove is dealing with closed non-empty nested intervals whose diameter approaches $0$. The statement in the wiki-entry is simply a dualization of the compactness definition.

Comment: You can see why you need bounded, too, since $\bigcap_n [n,+\infty)$ is empty...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews- I think Cantor's Intersection Theorem is true for any complete metric space, and not only $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan Yes, but you need nested _closed_ sets whose diameter shrinks to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intervals $F_n$ are *closed* intervals, and hence, are a positive distance from any point outside of them. More generally, in any metric space, closed sets are a positive distance from any point outside them, since the closed set's complement is an open neighborhood of the point.